# ASP.NET MVCContrib Grid with Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

Where can I find some sample projects that show jquery ajax integrated with the MVCContrib Grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [blog post](http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/ajax-enabling-mvccontrib-grid-pagination-with-jquery/) which illustrates how to perform paging using AJAX. And here's a [nice plugin for the grid](http://mvcajax.codeplex.com/) allowing you to perform AJAX paging and sorting.